# Evaluation of a Function with Lagrangian Finite Element

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Suppose we want to evaluate a function, derived through linear Lagrangian finite element, in a point which is not one of its nodes. Is a simple linear interpolation equal to the correct evaluation of the finite element function (i.e., a sum of weighted local tent function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. After all, that is what your FE model says.

However, this assumes that the node values that you interpolate from are results from the FEM computation. If instead you have the computed node values e. g. squared, then you should not interpolate the squared values, of course.

The story would also be different if you wanted to fit your degrees of freedom to some scattered data points. Reversing the interpolation is usually not optimal, and sometimes impossible (due to contradictions). But that is not the case here.

Comment: Thank you. I asked this question because in the solution of an assignment solved in Matlab, they decided to compute the basis functions in the new points and apply the definition of the finite element function, instead of simply using Matlab function interp1.

Comment: Well, the first approach is the general one. It allows one to switch to other finite elements (e.g. second order) without having to change much code outside their definition. That may be the rationale.

Comment: But if we had a higher order finite element, we would have to evaluate the function in more nodes, proportional to the order we want to obtain. At the end, couldn't we just apply a polynomial interpolation of that order to estimate the function in some new points?

Comment: Yes, since the interpolation matches the definition of the finite element functions. That is the general requirement, and the Matlab code you have been wondering about seems to work from first prinicples here. Of course, your version is then somewhat optimized.